# What are XSLT Result Trees

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am reading a book on XSLT 2.0. I am on the chapter of XSLT Result Trees. Frankly, i don't understand it a bit. What are result trees? What is it used for? Why is it important?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a detailed explanation.

Comment: What does the book say about them that you don't understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**From the [W3C XSLT 2.0 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#terminology)**:

> "[Definition: The term result tree is
>   used to refer to any tree constructed
>   by instructions in the stylesheet. A
>   result tree is either a final result
>   tree or a temporary tree.]
>
> [Definition: A final result tree is a
>   result tree that forms part of the
>   final output of a transformation. Once
>   created, the contents of a final
>   result tree are not accessible within
>   the stylesheet itself.] The
>   xsl:result-document instruction always
>   creates a final result tree, and a
>   final result tree may also be created
>   implicitly by the initial template."

This means that all output from the XSLT transformation is a set of result trees (this will be a single result tree if no `<xsl:result-document>` is used).

Also, any *temporary tree* like one created in the body of an `<xsl:variable>` (that isn't produced as a separate output, but is used internally in the course of the transformation) is a result tree.

It is important to know that any XSLT transformation operates on trees and the result of the transformation is also a set of trees.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that result trees also are used within the transformation and not only produced as a result of the transformation.

Answer (score 2):

XML documents [form trees](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_tree.asp). A result tree is simply the name for the new tree you create after running an XSL transformation on a source tree: "A transformation expressed in XSLT describes rules for transforming zero or more source trees into one or more result trees" [(from W3C)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/).